# Owl Carousel prev button is not working when i navigate from another page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

i have an two separate pages. For example let's say firs and second page.

I have an owl carousel slider on my first page thats having a  tag thats href to the specific slide on my second page owl carousel slider. with and id. On the second page i have an prev and next buttons thats changing names every time user changes the slide so it helps them to know where are going to. Until this point everything works correct but the problem is for example if the user clicks the second slider from the first page and it does navigate user to the second page and loads the second slider but if i straight click the prev button its not working. Lets repeat the same scenario but this time insntead of clicking the prev button lets click the next button it does work. Also if i click the next button first then click the prev button it also works. But somehow when i navigate to the second page from the first one and click the prev button firstly its being messed up heres my codes.

**FIRST PAGE**

```
<div class="owl-carousel home-page-project-design home-page-manufacturing-list">

        <a href="../project-design-showcase.php#walk-in-wardrobes">
            <div class="image-div">
                <div class="image-container">
                  <img class="home-page-manufacturing-list-img" src="../images/walk-in-closets-and-wardrobes-images/1.webp" alt="Image 1">
                </div>
                <div class="image-text">Walk-in Wardrobes</div>
            </div>
          </a>

          <a href="../project-design-showcase.php#bedrooms">
            <div class="image-div">
                <div class="image-container">
                  <img class="home-page-manufacturing-list-img" src="../images/bedrooms-images/1.webp" alt="Image 2">
                </div>
                <div class="image-text">Bedrooms</div>
            </div>
          </a>

          <a href="../project-design-showcase.php#bathroom-and-vanities">
            <div class="image-div">
                <div class="image-container">
                  <img class="home-page-manufacturing-list-img" src="../images/bathroom-and-vanities-images/1.webp" alt="Image 3">
                </div>
                <div class="image-text">Bathroom & Vanities</div>
            </div>
          </a>

          <a href="../project-design-showcase.php#kitchen-and-islands">
            <div class="image-div">
                <div class="image-container">
                  <img class="home-page-manufacturing-list-img" src="../images/kitchen-and-islands-images/5.webp" alt="Image 3">
                </div>
                <div class="image-text">Kitchen & Islands</div>
            </div>
           </a>

           <a href="../project-design-showcase.php#seatings">
            <div class="image-div">
                <div class="image-container">
                  <img class="home-page-manufacturing-list-img" src="../images/seatings-images/8.webp" alt="Image 3">
                </div>
                <div class="image-text">Seatings</div>
            </div>
           </a>

           <a href="../project-design-showcase.php#bars">
            <div class="image-div">
                <div class="image-container">
                  <img class="home-page-manufacturing-list-img" src="../images/bars-images/13.webp" alt="Image 3">
                </div>
                <div class="image-text">Bars</div>
            </div>
           </a>

           <a href="../project-design-showcase.php#outdoors">
            <div class="image-div">
                <div class="image-container">
                  <img class="home-page-manufacturing-list-img" src="../images/outdoors-images/1.webp" alt="Image 3">
                </div>
                <div class="image-text">Outdoors</div>
            </div>
           </a>
 </div>
```

**SECOND PAGE**

```
    <section class="next-and-previous-title-showcase">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="custom-nav">
                        <button class="prev-button">Previous</button>
                        <button class="next-button">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



<div class="owl-carousel test3">
    <div id="walk-in-wardrobes"><?php include './project-design-showcase-list/walk-in-wardrobes.php';?></div>
    <div id="bedrooms"><?php include './project-design-showcase-list/bedrooms.php';?></div>
    <div id="bathroom-and-vanities"><?php include './project-design-showcase-list/bathrooms-and-vanities.php';?></div>
    <div id="kitchen-and-islands"><?php include './project-design-showcase-list/kitchen-and-islands.php';?></div>
    <div id="seatings"><?php include './project-design-showcase-list/seatings.php';?></div>
    <div id="bars"><?php include './project-design-showcase-list/bars.php';?></div>
    <div id="outdoors"><?php include './project-design-showcase-list/outdoors.php';?></div>
</div>



<script>




$(document).ready(function(){
    var owl = $('.test3').owlCarousel({
        stagePadding: 10,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            768: {
                items: 1
            },
            1280: {
                items: 1
            }
        },
        touchDrag: false,
        mouseDrag: false
    });


    var nextButtonLabels = [
        'Bedrooms',
        'Bathroom & Vanities',
        'Kitchen & Islands',
        'Seatings',
        'Bars',
        'Outdoor',
        ''
    ];

    var prevButtonLabels = [
        '',
        'Walk-In Wardrobe',
        'Bedrooms',
        'Bathroom & Vanities',
        'Kitchen & Islands',
        'Seatings',
        'Bars'
    ];

    // Get the fragment identifier from the URL
    var fragment = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    // Map fragment identifiers to their corresponding slide indices
    var fragmentMap = {
        'walk-in-wardrobes': 0,
        'bedrooms': 1,
        'bathroom-and-vanities': 2,
        'kitchen-and-islands': 3,
        'seatings': 4,
        'bars': 5,
        'outdoors': 6
    };

    // Set the initial currentItem based on the fragment identifier
    var currentItem = 0; // Default to the first slide
    if (fragmentMap.hasOwnProperty(fragment)) {
        currentItem = fragmentMap[fragment];
    }

    // Update button labels based on the current active item index
    function updateButtonLabels() {
        $('.prev-button').text(prevButtonLabels[currentItem]);
        $('.next-button').text(nextButtonLabels[currentItem]);
    }

    // Initialize button labels based on the initial currentItem
    updateButtonLabels();

    $('.prev-button').click(function() {
        if (currentItem > 0) {
            owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
            currentItem--;
            updateButtonLabels();
        }
    });

    $('.next-button').click(function() {
        if (currentItem < prevButtonLabels.length - 1) {
            owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
            currentItem++;
            updateButtonLabels();
        }
    });
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fragmentMap = {
        'walk-in-wardrobes': 0,
        'bedrooms': 1,
        'bathroom-and-vanities': 2,
        'kitchen-and-islands': 3,
        'seatings': 4,
        'bars': 5,
        'outdoors': 6
    };

    var owl = $('.test3').owlCarousel({
        stagePadding: 10,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            768: {
                items: 1
            },
            1280: {
                items: 1
            }
        },
        touchDrag: false,
        mouseDrag: false
    });

    function updateButtonLabels(currentItem) {
        $('.prev-button').text(prevButtonLabels[currentItem]);
        $('.next-button').text(nextButtonLabels[currentItem]);
    }

    var nextButtonLabels = [
        'Bedrooms',
        'Bathroom & Vanities',
        'Kitchen & Islands',
        'Seatings',
        'Bars',
        'Outdoor',
        ''
    ];

    var prevButtonLabels = [
        '',
        'Walk-In Wardrobe',
        'Bedrooms',
        'Bathroom & Vanities',
        'Kitchen & Islands',
        'Seatings',
        'Bars'
    ];

    var currentItem = 0;

    // Get the fragment identifier from the URL
    var fragment = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (fragmentMap.hasOwnProperty(fragment)) {
        currentItem = fragmentMap[fragment];
    }

    // Initialize the Owl Carousel with the currentItem
    owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [currentItem, 0, true]);
    updateButtonLabels(currentItem);

    $('.prev-button').click(function() {
        if (currentItem > 0) {
            owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
            currentItem--;
            updateButtonLabels(currentItem);
        }
    });

    $('.next-button').click(function() {
        if (currentItem < prevButtonLabels.length - 1) {
            owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
            currentItem++;
            updateButtonLabels(currentItem);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```